# Unable to render data for datatable in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, datatables

I am unable to get the data from an API into a datatable in reactjs.Totally a newbie here. It return data just the values but not rendering it withing the datatable form

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

const $ = require("jquery");
$.DataTable = require("datatables.net");

class Tables extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("table is ", this.el);
    let element = $(this.el);
    element.DataTable({
      data: this.props.data,
      columns: [{ title: "Key" }, { title: "Value" }],
    });

    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10")
      .then(results => {
        console.log("results are ", results);
        return results.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log("data is ", data);
        let pictures = data.results.map((value, index) => {
          console.log("picture is ", value);
          console.log("index is", index);

          return (
            <table className="display" ref={el => (this.el = el)}>
              {this.value.registered.date}
            </table>
          );
        });
        this.setState({ pictures: pictures });
        console.log("state", this.state.pictures);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <table className="display" ref={el => (this.el = el)}>
        {this.state.pictures}
      </table>
    );
  }
}
export default Tables;
```

Comment: How `this.props.data` looks?

Answer (score 0):

My API response is in this format { "teen1":"100","teen2":"200"}. However the ttable excepts in this format  ["teen1", "100"], ["teen1", "100"]. That is the reason I beleive its not able to take the data